Angular Jest mock post request
First time using jest and I'm having some big problems on mocking a service with a post method request. I think I spend more than 6 hours on this and still can't pass it.
I would appreaciate any help.
First I'll say about libraries versions. As ChatGpt told, those should be compatible with each other. jest: 29.7.0, jest-preset-angular: 14.4.2, ts-jest: 29.2.5, ts-node: 10.9.2, typescript: 5.5.2, angular/cli: 18.2.11, angular/core: 18.2.0.
Method which I want to test is this one, from Registration component:
submitForm(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.contactFormGroup.valid) {
      this.errorForm = true;
      return;
    }

    this.errorForm = false;
    const registerSub = this.coreService.registerUser(this.contactFormGroup.value).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        alert(response.message);
        this.contactFormGroup.reset();
      },
      error: () => {
        alert('There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again');
        this.contactFormGroup.reset();
      },
    });
    this.subscriptions.add(registerSub)
  }
registerUser from coreserver:
  registerUser(userData: userData): Observable<RequestType> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
  
    return this.httpClient.post<RequestType>('http://localhost:3000/register', userData, { headers});
  }


What i tried:
describe('RegistrationComponent', () => {
  let component: RegistrationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RegistrationComponent>;
  let mockCoreService: CoreService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockCoreService = MockService(CoreService);
    
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: CoreService, useValue: mockCoreService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RegistrationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should submit form successfully', fakeAsync(() => {
    const mockResponse = { message: 'Registration successful' };
    jest.spyOn(mockCoreService, 'registerUser').mockReturnValue(of({ message: 'Registration successful!', status: 'success' }));
    jest.spyOn(window, 'alert');
    
    component.contactFormGroup.setValue({
      username: 'testuser',
      fullname: 'Test User',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'TestPass123!'
    });
    
    const event = new Event('submit');
    event.preventDefault();
    component.submitForm(event);
    tick(100);
    
    expect(mockCoreService.registerUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockResponse.message);
  }));

The problem is here:
expect(mockCoreService.registerUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
I just can t mock this line and the method is not mocked correctly. this is what I think and what i tested even with console logs inside next observable and error in .ts file.
error by npm run test:
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
If you have any idea how to solve this, I would appreciate.
I also tried with ng-mock and also something like:
let coreServiceSpy: jest.Mocked<CoreService>;


  beforeEach(async () => {
    coreServiceSpy = {
      registerUser: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of({ message: 'Registration successful!', status: 'success' })),
    } as any;

and in test:
coreServiceSpy.registerUser.mockReturnValue(of({ message: 'Registration successful!', status: 'success' }));
